# Rails Paperclip::AdapterRegistry::NoHandlerError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip, activeadmin

#### Error

```
Paperclip::AdapterRegistry::NoHandlerError at /admin/posts/1 No handler found for foo.png
```

I have a rails 4 app with Active Admin and im trying to upload an image to my Post model but I am getting the above error. Here is my setup

#### Gemfile

```
ruby '2.1.2'

gem 'rails', '4.1.6'
gem 'activeadmin', github: 'gregbell/active_admin'
gem 'paperclip'
gem 'aws-sdk'
```

#### Model

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_attached_file :image, styles: {
    thumb: '100x100>',
    square: '200x200#',
    medium: '300x300>'
  }
  validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/

end
```

#### Active Admin

```
permit_params :image

form do |f|
  f.inputs do
    f.input :image, as: :file, hint: (f.template.image_tag(f.object.image.url(:thumb)) if f.object.image?)
  end
  f.actions
end
```

#### /config/initializers/paperclip.rb

```
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:storage] = :s3
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:s3_host_name] = 's3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com'
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:url] = ':s3_domain_url'
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:path] = '/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename'
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:s3_protocol] = 'http'
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:s3_credentials] = 
  { :bucket => 'foo-production',
    :access_key_id => 'XXXXXXXXXXXX',
    :secret_access_key => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX' }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So this is the answer:

```
form :html => {:multipart => true} do |f|
  f.inputs do
    f.input :image, as: :file, hint: (f.template.image_tag(f.object.image.url(:thumb)) if f.object.image?)
  end
  f.actions
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have imagemagick installed?

On OS X if you have homebrew, it's easy as `brew install imagemagick`. For windows, get the .exe.

http://www.imagemagick.org/

Imagemagick does the resizing / image manipulation for Paperclip.

Comment: Yes I do $ brew install imagemagick
Warning: imagemagick-6.8.9-8 already installed

Comment: try adding multipart: true to the form

Comment: Yes, for some reason that worked. Never had to do that before unless it was a feature that has come in Rails 4.1 with activeadmin 1.0.0pre